# SC Delete Not Deleting Service

Tags: windows, service, windows-server-2008

So I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard and am trying to delete a service with '`sc delete <myservicesname>`' and the command seems to execute without complaint, however, when I check the services list after running the command, the service is still there.

Any ideas?

Comment: I found Brian's answer correct.

Comment: Brian's answer also helped me out, since I was using powershell, and sc just looked like it did nothing.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

sc in PowerShell is Set-Content; so if you are running in PowerShell, you likely have a file called 'delete' with your service's name as its content

If this is indeed your issue, use

```
sc.exe delete servicename
```

Comment: Helped me out as well. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. I was doing sc delete servicename , without .exe

Answer (score 20):

Service can be marked for deletion, but may not be deleted immediately, since something holds it. See this answer for possible holders: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20565337/1943849

In my case, I just closed the `Computer Management` window

Comment: Most unexpected fix, there is no indication a service is marked for deletion

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to stop the service first then run the sc delete command. It will take care of closing any running process.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in PowerShell, although Remove-Service cmdlet is only available in PowerShell versions 6.0 and up

```
$SERVICE_NAME

get-service | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $SERVICE_NAME} | Stop_Service

try{
    if((Get-Host | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Version).Major -ge 6){
        Remove-Service -Name $SERVICE_NAME
    }else{
        sc.exe delete $SERVICE_NAME
    }
}catch{
    Write-Output $_.exception.message
}
```

You can find the docs for Remove-Service cmdlet [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-service?view=powershell-7.2)